# How to set default value for multiple inputs from one line in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-input

I'm trying to get specifications three necessary inputs and a fourth optional one from one input in Python.

```
a, b, c, d = input("Please enter the number of the figure you would like and the x y coordinated in that order and a colour if you choose.").split()
```

I want `d` to be optional with a set default value but I'm really struggling with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
# get input
inp = input("Please enter the number of the figure you would like and the x y coordinated in that order and a colour if you choose.").split()
# check how many parameters are passed
if len(input) == 3:
    # value for d is not passed
    a, b, c = inp
    d = default_value
else:
    # value for d is passed
    a, b, c, d = inp
```

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is:

```
answers = input("...").split()
if len(answers) < 4:
    answers.append( default_value_for_4 )
```

If you really really feel the need to have them called a, b, c, d, then just do:

```
a, b, c, d = answers
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
a, b, c, d, *_ = (input("...") + " <default value>").split()
```

This will assign `d` to `<default value>` if there are only 3 inputs.

If there are 4 inputs then `d` will be assigned to the fourth value, and the value of the variable `_` will be `<default value>` (which is a Python convention to discard a value).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code

```
a , b , *c = input("Please enter the number of the figure you would like and the x y coordinated in that order and a colour if you choose.").split()
```

If there are multiple inputs, all will get saved in `c` which you can further process and assign it to variable `d`